# Pass the value of the input type tag that is inside of a while loop where the while loops is inside the php

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql

Help me get the value of total amount where:
 1 column is displays the amount from db (I while looped it), multiply it by input tag ((no of copies). this is inside the while loop) then multiply them to get the total amount. How to pass the value of my input tag in php while loop?

Here is the image:

[image]

```
<?php       
    $result = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM account_db");
    $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);   
    echo"<html>";
    echo"<center>";
    echo "<form method='POST'>";
    echo "<table style='border:1px solid black' name='pleasework'>";
    echo"<th>FILES</th>";
    echo"<th>AMOUNT</th>";
    echo"<th>NO. OF COPIES</th>";
    echo"<th>TOTAL AMOUNT</th>";

    $answer = $row[2] * noofcopies;

    while($row)
    {
        echo"<tr>";
        echo "<td id='transfile'>$row[1] </td>";
        echo "<td align=center>$row[2] </td>";
        echo "<td align=center><input type='number' name='noofcopies' onkeyup> </td>";
        echo "<td align=center value=''>$answer</td>";
        echo"</tr>";
    }                   

    echo "</table>";
    echo " <input type='submit' value='Transact' name='transaction'>";
    echo"</center>";
    echo"</html>";      
?>
```

Comment: So you want to multiply; what have you tried with the `*`? I.e.: `$int1 * $int2`.

Comment: my input tag is in the php and inside the while loop how will i pass the value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe what you need is to use some javascript to update the total amount after user input the number of copy (`onkeyup` event).

```
<?php       
    $result = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM account_db");
    $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);   
    echo"<html>";
    echo "<script>";
    echo "function calculate(amount, id){ document.getElementById('total' + id).innerHTML = parseInt(document.getElementById('copy' + id).value) * amount; }";
    echo "</script>";
    echo"<center>";
    echo "<form method='POST'>";
    echo "<table style='border:1px solid black' name='pleasework'>";
    echo"<th>FILES</th>";
    echo"<th>AMOUNT</th>";
    echo"<th>NO. OF COPIES</th>";
    echo"<th>TOTAL AMOUNT</th>";

    $counter = 0;
    while($row)
    {
        echo"<tr>";
        echo "<td id='transfile'>$row[1] </td>";
        echo "<td align=center>$row[2] </td>";
        echo "<td align=center><input type='number' id='copy" . $counter . "' name='noofcopies' onkeyup='calculate(" . $row[2] .  ", " . $counter . ")'> </td>";
        echo "<td align=center value='' id='total" . $counter . "'></td>";
        echo"</tr>";
        $counter++;
    }                   

    echo "</table>";
    echo " <input type='submit' value='Transact' name='transaction'>";
    echo"</center>";
    echo"</html>";      
?>
```

The idea is first to set ID on the `input` and `td` for accessing via javascript.
Then, create a function to calculate the total.
Then, use `document.getElementById` function to get and set the value.
Further reading [HERE](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementbyid.asp).

Hope this help.

Comment: it worked but sadly it it only it dsiplays the first row repeatedly and infintely, the other rows are gone have any idea to debug this? ty

Comment: Nevermind It worked! Thanks! I moved the  $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result); inside the while (/*here*/){ ...  } instead putting the decalred variable only! thanks Mr. Viki !!!

Comment: How to get the overall total value of the total amount column?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't given us the name of the column in the DB, of the name or the field in the form.
Something like:

```
$inputVal=$_REQUEST['my_input_field'];
$sql = sprintf("SELECT SUM(my_col)*%d FROM account_db", $inputVal);
```

where you replace my_input_field and my_col with the real values should work.

Comment: yes i havent but the $row[1] and $row[2] displays them... i put the image of my code